# Not able to download files from S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

This is the code i am using to download all the files from my S3 bucket is:

```
#Download all files from a bucket to a local folder
        LOCAL_PATH = "C\\s3\\"
        bucket_name = 'unrendered'
        # connect to the bucket
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        # go through the list of files
        for key in bucket.list():
            try:
                res = key.get_contents_to_filename(key.name).replace("\\", "//")
            except:
                print(key.name+":"+"FAILED")
```

The files in my S3 buckets are:

[image]

The code only downloads the first file, but i cannot download the rest of the files which have names with directory address included.

Also, when i upload the files on S3 using boto, it does not create directories it creates  files with names of directories included. I know that s3 is flat data structure, but how can i create folder from the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

In line #9, try replacing your line with this:

```
   res = key.get_contents_to_filename(key.name.replace("\\", ""))
```

Does that work?